# Using the InputMethodManager in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm attempting to have a seekbar so that the user can adjust the value of an edittext box in a fragment. Here is where I use it:

```
...

//NOTE: This is in the onCreateView() method for a Fragment
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         seekBar.setProgress(seekBar.getProgress() + 1);
         editText.setText(String.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress()));

         //Hidden method call not needed to be visible...

         //Notice the InputMethodManager, also, this is line 197...
         InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(                                    
              Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

         imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(seekBar.getWindowToken(), 0);

    }
});

...
```

Here is the Logcat output:

```
03-09 00:00:41.164      573-573/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.hidden.hidden.hidden.onClick(Hidden.java:197)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Note that the package name is hidden for security reasons.

Any help is appreciated!

**Edit:** Notice that on line 197, I didn't have "context." there. It gave me and error so I declared a global variable like this: `Context context;`

Comment: Which one is line 197?

Comment: What you want do? clear first

Comment: @AndyFaizan See edits...

Comment: @SimplePlan I am trying to use a seekbar to edit text in an edittext

Comment: @AndrewQ if I've understand which is the 197 line..looks like the `context` instance is null, could you try to replace `context.getSystemService(..)` with `getActivity().getSystemService()`?

Comment: @AndyFaizan I found a solution and marked the best answer. I do, however, appreciate your feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     seekBar.setProgress(seekBar.getProgress() + 1);
     editText.setText(String.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress()));

    try{
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(                                    
          Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

     imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(seekBar.getWindowToken(), 0);

    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
     }

  }
});
```

Give me feedback on this.

Answer (score 2):

Dont use `getActivity()` instead use `requireActivity()` like this

`InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);`

And in your fragment dont do this in the `onCreateView` instead do this in the `onViewCreated` to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
Context context = getActivity(); //since you're in a fragment


      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 seekBar.setProgress(seekBar.getProgress() + 1);
                 editText.setText(String.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress()));

                 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(                                    
                      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(seekBar.getWindowToken(), 0);

            }
        });
```

**EDIT**: Don't call `getActivity()` before `onAttach()`. It will return null otherwise.